# Unable to cast object of type 'AttachmentDetailsDto' to type 'System.String'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Have method

`public async Task<IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, AttachmentDetailsDto>>> GetAttachmentsAsync(long assetInfoId)`

within it I do...

```
var results = new List<AttachmentDetailsDto>();
var attachmentEntities = await _attachmentRepository.GetAsync(x => x.ParentAssetInfoId == assetInfoId && !x.IsDeleted).ConfigureAwait(false);

foreach (var attachmentEntity in attachmentEntities)
{
    var attachmentTypeEntity = await _attachmentTypeRepository.GetByIdAsync(attachmentEntity.MetattachTypeId).ConfigureAwait(false);

    var metattachDetail = new AttachmentDetailsDto
    {
        Id = attachmentEntity.Id,
        TypeId = attachmentEntity.MetattachTypeId,
        Type = attachmentTypeEntity.Name,
        Name = attachmentEntity.Name,
        Notes = attachmentEntity.Notes,
    };

    attachmentType = attachmentEntity.MetaType;
    var assetInfoEntity = default(AssetInfo);

    switch (attachmentType)
    {
        case "DigiDoc":
            var digiDocEntity = await _digiDocRepository.GetByIdAsync(attachmentEntity.TypeId).ConfigureAwait(false);
            metattachDetail.DigiDoc = new DigiDocDto
            {
                Id = digiDocEntity.Id,
                ContentType = digiDocEntity.ContentType,
                Url = digiDocEntity.Url
            };
            break;
... other cases ...
    }
    results.Add(metattachDetail);
}

return results.GroupBy(x => x.Type);
```

No errors here, but in my controller...

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> GetAttachmentsAsync(long assetInfoId)
        {
            var result = await _attachmentManager.GetAttachmentsAsync(assetInfoId).ConfigureAwait(false);
            return Ok(result);
        }
```

An error is thrown on line "`return Ok(result);`"

... I don't understand it, same code in .Net Framework works perfectly, now in .Net Core 3.1 it errors...

**Error:**

Unable to cast object of type 'AttachmentDetailsDto' to type 'System.String'.

**Stack Trace:**

at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfoNotNullable'4.OnWriteEnumerable(WriteStackFrame& current, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfo.WriteEnumerable(WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.HandleEnumerable(JsonClassInfo elementClassInfo, JsonSerializerOptions options, Utf8JsonWriter writer, WriteStack& state)
at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Int32 originalWriterDepth, Int32 flushThreshold, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.d__50.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter.d__5.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter.d__5.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<g__Logged|21_0>d.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<g__Awaited|29_0>d`2.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<g__Awaited|24_0>d.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<g__Logged|17_1>d.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0>d.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.d__5.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.d__6.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.d__5.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at HomeaZZon.Api.Middlewares.ExceptionMiddleware.d__3.MoveNext() in C:\repo\homeazzon\api\api-.core-monolothic\HomeaZZon.Api\Middlewares\ExceptionMiddleware.cs:line 28

...

**Startup.cs**

...

```
            services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(o =>
            {
                o.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true;
                o.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
            });
```

Comment: System.Text.Json is still in its infancy, there are a lot of known limitations. Switch to Newtonsoft.Json if you want the same level of support you had in ASP.NET 4.x

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto how/where do I make this change at? I don't recall specifying usage of System.Text.Json... In my controller I don't see a "using" referencing that library nor in my manager. hmmmm......

Comment: System.Text.Json is the default since 3.0. Look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#use-newtonsoftjson-in-an-aspnet-core-30-mvc-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone else mentioned, it's hard to really nail down your error but if you simply want the same functionality you had in .NET Framework in terms of serialization, then here's how you do it.

Install the following nuget package :

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson
```

Then in your services method you'll have something like "AddMVC". Modify that like so :

```
services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

More info : https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/12/19/using-newtonsoft-json-in-net-core-3-projects/

.NET Core projects 3+ use a new JSON serializer that honestly isn't bad, but has a couple of issues here and there. The performance benefits in later versions are a pretty big boon, but if you just need things to be exactly like they were before, then you need to use JSON.NET (With the above instructions), and you'll be back to old times!

Comment: thanks @MindingData... I added it and it worked temporarily... but I really don't like doing things like that... I'd rather use the new System.Text.Json as it was/is intended. Can you refer me to a good article that would help me find a solution to my problem w/System.Text.Json?

Comment: Honestly. If you create a minimal reproducible example and upload it to GIT, you can add a bug to the Github repo https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues

Comment: awesome, let me add this to my backlog!